# Restrict list drop down choice

Tags: 2007, list

I have a list of requests and I want to restrict the users from skipping a Status, so if the list item is at Status 3 they can only change it to 4.

This is because everytime the request moves to the next Status, the date is logged. If a Status is skipped then the KPIs make no sense!

I only have client side functionality so if the answer is no please let me know!

[image: Status screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have javascript skills, you could use javascript to filter the dropdown list based on logic.

For example, you could put this in a content editor web part on the page (below the edit form web part):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("ctlid000-blahblah");

  // Find the selected status. 
  var selectedItem = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

  // Logic for if the selected item is draft.
  if (selectedItem == "1")
  {
      foreach(var opt in dropdown.options) {
         // remove the draft option.
         // You can remove whichever other items you want too.
        if (opt.value == "1")
         {
           dropdown.remove(opt);
         }
      }
  }
</ script>
```

To add webparts to the EditForm.aspx, you can simple add "&ToolPaneView=2" to the Url.